# boost::thread compilation error in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, boost

I'm trying ot use boost for the first time in a long while and when I include the boost/thread.hpp header I get a compilation error inside boost itself:

```
    c:\myproj\boost_1_46_0\boost\thread\win32\thread_heap_alloc.hpp(97): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'heap_memory
    c:\myproj\boost_1_46_0\boost\thread\detail\thread.hpp(134) : see reference to function template instantiation 'T *boost::detail::heap_new<boost::detail::thread_data<F>,void(__cdecl *)(void)>(A1 &&)' being compiled
    with
    [
        T=boost::detail::thread_data<void (__cdecl *)(void)>,
        F=void (__cdecl *)(void),
        A1=void (__cdecl *)(void)
    ]`
```

This happens just by including the header, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with my code, but I can't see what to do about it, can anyone help?

Comment: I don't see how the code inside boost can ever compile, it is using a variable name (`heap_memory`) as a type cast:
`void* const heap_memory=allocate_raw_heap_memory... 
T* const data = new (heap_memory) T....`

Comment: I thought I had worked around this by defining `BOOST_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES`, but this just postponed the problem until I tried to call a constructor that took a parameter.  The boost code just isn't sensible!!

Comment: VS2010 does have rvalue references, so that is not a problem. The `new (heap_memory)` is not a typecast, but a placement new. The object is constructed at *heap_memory, just allocated.

Comment: what did you include before this header ?

Comment: I don't think I included anything special before the header, should I have done?  If so, why doesn't boost include that dependency itself?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the MSVC wizard, make sure to include the boost header

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
```

before the generated block

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible you #included some other package that has a #define of 'new', which then breaks what Boost is trying to do with placement new.
To see the code after pre-processing, compile with /P or /E and then search for this line in the output and see if it looks different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I known the problem. You can find something interest from  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/683483/mfc-c-fails-to-compile-use-of-codecvt-utf8-in-debug-configuration